# Cannot view SSRS 2008 R2 Reports in Safari/Opera but works fine in Chrome / IE8… why?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i developed and deployed report and it is working fine 
in chrome and internet explorer the report is working then

firefox , opera and safari asking username and passwords .

can any body share their ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

"it is very normal for the SSRS to prompt for username and password. In fact, it actually prompts for username and password in all browsers. The fact that IE9 does not prompt for username/password is simply because you may have stored the credentials on the browser cache."

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1765440.aspx/1

Comment: Neil , i refered your URL, in our local we can full fill our requirement by adding our server URL into firefox trusted site but we cannot ask the client to do all these steps. and also most of my client client's default browser may be opera or safari browsers.